# passing variable into driver.execute_script() in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i was trying to open link in a new tab. and the method i uses is like below.

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers/","_blank");''')
```

the above code works but i want to add some variable into it to construct full url like this below.

```
https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers/us/A294P4X9EWVXLJ/ankerdirect
```

this is what i have tried so far

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers/`{country}`/`{id}`","_blank");''')
```

but when it opened it adds other things, which gives me the output as below.

```
https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers/%60%7Bcountry%7D%60/%60%7Bid%7D%60
```

it is adding `%60%7Bcountry%7D%60/%60%7Bid%7D%60` after `https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string like below :

I have taken num string and name string and parsing with `%s`

see the below code :

```
driver.get("https://www.tracksellers.com/")
num = "A294P4X9EWVXLJ"
name = "ankerdirect"
new_url = 'https://www.tracksellers.com/sellers/us/%s/%s/'  % (num, name)
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{new_url}","_blank");''')
```